# multiple domains point to same site on WP-MU

Tags: multisite, urls, domain

I have setup Wordpress Multisite on a bitnami image (on AWS).  I have numerous domains working fine, each with their own WP site.  (eg: a.com, b.com, c.com)

I also have some alias domains (a1.com, a2.com, a3.com) that I would like to be handled by the existing a.com wordpress site.

I have setup dns to point a1.com to the same host as a.com.  But this always takes me to the default WP site with the message about creating a new site.  Not what I want.

I don't want to edit the VirtualHost settings in apache if possible.  Is there a way for WordPress to accept all 4 domain names as the same site (a.com) ?

I have it working by creating a separate site for a1.com, another for a2.com etc, and using a redirect plugin to use a 503 to send the user to a.com.  However, this seems too complicated.  Surely there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If they're just to get visitors there and you don't care about making the site "look like" the alias domains, you can just 301 redirect the site using .htaccess or similar. If instead you want to make it "look like" visitors are on the alias domains then you may need to work with your host to figure out how to mask the URLs. Keep in mind this may have negative consequences for SEO so unless you absolutely must mask things, it's probably better to redirect instead.

Comment: bitnami disables htaccess, but I can place rewrite rules into each virtual host.  But then I would have to create a virtual host for each alias (I assume).  I don't mind redirect 503 to the main site, I just want to keep it simple